# Why can't I use "easierly" instead of "in an easier manner" or "more easily"?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, superlative-degree

Can you please explain why it is incorrect English?

Comment: You can if you want. It's not necessarily incorrect. Native speakers don't say that, however. Which is what makes it "incorrect".

Comment: Explaining this is easierly said than done.

Comment: There is no particular reason, other that the word in not in major dictionaries. The question is that adding the suffix -ly to make an adverb is not done with any conceivable word.

Comment: *She gets up **earlier** than us* can be recast as [*She gets up more early than us*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gets+up+more+early+than%22). That's to say - ***earlier / more early*** and ***easier / more easily*** can be syntactically and semantically interchangeable, so there's no *need* to include both comparative ***-er*** and adverbial ***-ly*** suffixes.

Comment: Fasterly? Quieterly? Sillierly? Fuzzierly? Making comparative adverbs from the corresponding comparative adjectives by adding -ly is not a rule in English.

Answer (score 5):

Historically, people interested in expressing the idea "more easily" in a single word seem to have preferred *easilier* to *easierly*. Here are the Ngram results for *easilier* (blue line) versus *easierly* (red line) for the period 1750–2000:

[image]

The results are actually skewed in *easierly*'s favor by multiple OCR misreadings of *easterly* as *easierly*; such misreadings account for the great majority of the early reported matches for *easierly*. In contrast, most of the matches for *easilier* are legitimate; and the frequency of its usage increases the farther back in history you go. Here is the corresponding Ngram chart for 1600–2008:

[image]

Nevertheless, instances of *easierly* do exist, perhaps most prominently in this sentence from Fenimore Cooper's [*The Deerslayer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tnkPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA422&dq=%22easierly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8wMqeuYnUAhUhwVQKHUaUDkAQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22easierly%22&f=false) (1841):

> "Hark'ee, Sarpent," he [Deerslayer] continued more gravely, though too simply for affectation ; "this is **easierly** explained than an Indian brain may fancy. The sun, while he seems to keep travelling in the heavens, never budges, but it is the 'arth that turns round ; and any one can understand, if he is placed on the side of a mill-wheel, for instance, when it's in motion, that he must sometimes see the heavens, while he is at other times under water. There's no great secret in that, but plain natur' ; the difficulty being in setting the 'arth in motion."

A more recent instance occurs in [*ISEC '88: International Solvent Extraction Conference*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WJBKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22easierly%22&dq=%22easierly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAmsDvu4nUAhVniFQKHaFAAHM4ChDoAQgnMAA) (1988):

> In standard cases more effective extractants will demonstrate higher selectivity since they **easierly** enter the inner lantanide sphere destroying the hydratic sphere and forming corresponding solvates or complexes (for example, helato-forming reagents.) (Fig.7-9).

So, yes, you can say "easierly" (or "easilier") instead of "in an easier manner" or "more easily"—and after a moment's thought, most of your listeners or readers will probably understand that you are using the word to mean "in an easier manner" or "more easily." They may also think, "Why is he using that weird word instead of the phrase that everybody else uses?" But such is the price (as Fenimore Cooper well knew) of rejecting the familiar paths of common language and striking out across the untrammeled wastes of possible language, a pathfinder in one's own mind.